# Access denied for user when importing a dump of a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to move my mediawiki database from a Raspberry Pi to an Intel NUC.
I have MariaDB and Mediawiki installed on the NUC.  From the terminal on the NUC (running Ubuntu Server), I can create the target database:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
 CREATE DATABASE b_wiki;
 CREATE USER 'steve'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my02jeep';
 GRANT ALL ON mediawiki.* TO 'steve'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my02jeep' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 SHOW DATABASES;
 EXIT;
```

But when I try to import the sql file from the Raspberry Pi:
as root:

```
mysql -u root -p b_wiki < /tmp/backup_tuesday.sql
```

OR as the user I just created:

```
mysql -u steve -p b_wiki < /tmp/backup_tuesday.sql
```

I get as user steve:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'steve'@'localhost' to database 'b_wiki'
```

Or for user root:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe your Mysql uses the Auth Plugin... https://blog.ndk.name/change-mysql-server-authentication-plugin-for-root-user/

Comment: Thanks rené.  Running the select plugin command on the NUC, I get|' unix_socket'.  
Should I change 'unix_socket' to 'mysql_native_password' anyway?

Comment: For me I use the plugin for the root user and create a user that has only permissions for his database. These users use mysql_native_password for login.

Comment: I know this is against the rules, but thanks- this fixed it: UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password';